# How to post list<model> object back to controller action method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm trying to post a list object back to controller action method from a table, to export data as csv.

Let me know if I have done it the right way, on cshtml and action method.

[image]

```html
@model List<RapidFinanceCodeBehindBusinessLogic.ViewModels.SharedViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "GetCompaniesFromUploadedFile";
    //var modelOrdered = Model.OrderByDescending(m=>m.CompanyName);
}

<h2>Get Companies From Uploaded File</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("ExportCompaniesListToCSV", "Home"))
{
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                @*<th>
                        @Html.ActionLink(Model.OrderByDescending(x => x.CompanyName))
                    </th>*@
                <th><a>Company Name</a></th>
                <th><a>Years in Business</a></th>
                <th><a>Contact Name</a></th>
                <th><a>Contact Phone Number</a></th>
                <th><a>Contact Email</a></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@item.CompanyName</td>
                    <td>@item.YearsInBusiness</td>
                    <td>@item.ContactName</td>
                    <td>@item.ContactPhoneNumber</td>
                    <td>@item.ContactEmail</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Export to CSV" class="btn btn-success" />
        </div>
    </div>

}
```

```html
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ExportCompaniesListToCSV(FormCollection model)
        {            
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            sw.WriteLine("\"Company Name\",\"Years in Business\",\"Contact Name\",\"Contact Phone Number\",\"Contact Email\"");

            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Exported_Users.csv");
            Response.ContentType = "text/csv";

            //foreach (var line in model)
            //{
            //    sw.WriteLine(string.Format("\"{0}\",\"{1}\",\"{2}\",\"{3}\"",
            //                               line.FirstName,
            //                               line.LastName,
            //                               line.Dob,
            //                               line.Email));
            //}

            Response.Write(sw.ToString());

            Response.End();
            return RedirectToAction("GetCompaniesFromUploadedFile");
        }
```

Finally I was able to figure that out and I have provided my answer below, I hope it helps someone. I really appreciate all the help.

Comment: You are attacking it the wrong way, instead you should fire a controller action, that will extract the table data (as you did to display it), pack it into CSV and then send it. To take this information from the user, can be manipulate by the user, and will cost you in bandwidth in case of large tables.

Comment: Thanks for responding Orel, I'm getting that table data after I parse 3 different text files with 3 different delimiters. I'm not sure how to proceed in a different way for exporting.

Comment: The actual requirement is to sort the table data using the column name (displayed in the figure) and export the data after the sort.

Comment: Then hold the 'sort' column name in the client side and when clicking export send it to the controller action that should retake it from those files, sort them by the value you send from the client, and send it to the client.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention the entire requirement, I not supposed to use any of the client side technologies, I just need to use c# and the app needs to be built on pure mvc, not even external controls.
I had absolutely no idea with those requirements said,  I was able to parse all the text files and reach put it into a html table, I'm unsure of (a) sorting using column (b) exporting to csv.

Comment: I'm guessing JavaScript will be allowed, but JavaScript libraries like Angular, React etc' aren't, which will make the job much easier, and you should ask if you can use pure JavaScript. But in case you can't, then you should make a mvc form that will have a dropdown that contain the column and another that contains the ascending\descending and a button to "Apply" those sorting. this will go to the controller action with the 2 newly parameters, e.g. 'CompanyName', 'Descending' and then you should sort it, and return it to the View, for export, the same just instead download the file.

Comment: First follow what @OrelEraki said and post with the form with the values of your Sorting, Ordering and Filter, then regenerate the data in your `ExportCompaniesListToCSV`, you can store the values for Sorting, Ordering and Filter as `Hidden`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to take advantage of asp.net MVC concepts like, temp data, view data, to pass the data from one controller action to another. The whole idea was not to use javascript libraries and bootstrapping, so used temp data and view data to achieve this.
Thanks for all the support, community.

Comment: I'm not sure why my question was down voted, I'm a learning programmer and I want to learn the approaches by asking the questions to the community.
I wasn't sure if I have made a mistake by asking. Because of the down voting I'm no longer able to ask questions and learn to code.
I do get a lot of questions, on everyday coding, but no place to ask my questions.
All I want is to learn and code, please help me community.
Thanks all for the support.